# Nested function returns an object not reflected in main component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my custom hook for making api call that returns isloading ,error state

```
const {isloading,error,sendRequest} = customhook()
```

`If(isloading){displaymodal`}

I need to make 2 sequential api calls using this hook

```
Apicall1()
{
sendRequest (url,data,Logic1) // api call 1
}

Logic1(){
sendRequest (url2,data, logic2) // api call 2
}

Logic2(){
```

console.log (xyz)}

The problem is states like loading and error returned by api call 2 are not reflected in main component. states returned by api call 1 works fine
As a result modal display is getting effected.

Why data returned by apicall2 is not reflected in main component state ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]